# How to know the directory from which a script is called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm running a script defined in my `package.json` defined like `"generate": "node generators/index.js"`and it simply runs when I run `npm run generate`.

My script generates a copy from a template folder that is in the root of my project, the thing is that it's creating the template copies to the same root folder, and what I want it to do is to create the copy in the folder where I'm currently in the terminal.

Eg. I am in `bin/data` I run my command and I want to create a copy of the folder from my template stored in `templates/state` so that the copy of this template will be created in `bin/data/state`

I was trying to use the `proccess.cwd()` method but it creates all in the root path as this is a method that is called in a script stored in root folder.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(process.env.PWD)` inside the node script.

Comment: Using `process.env.PWD` fails cross-platform, notably when running a npm script on Windows and the default shell is _cmd.exe_. The `PWD` environment variable exists on _*nix_ only.